# Nvidia "I Prefer Maximum Performance" Quick Switch?

Tags: windows, command-line, nvidia-graphics-card

fellow Windows users!

I want to be able to (quickly) switch between

- I Prefer **Maximum** Performance
- **Adaptive** Performance

Nvidia Control Panel

[image: Nvidia Control Panel IMAGE]

I've used **Autohotkey** as a quick hack, but there has to be smarter way (CLI)? I'd also prefer **NOT** to use **Nvidia Inspector**, as it has negative impact on performance. It can even lock P-states in an irreversible manner. (Drivers reinstall...sigh)

> **WHY DO I WANT TO DO IT?** Because it makes a difference. The GPU can get caught in a thrashing-state-loop, which happens as GPU load is inconsistent; triggering different P-States. This introduces performance loss and GPU lags.

Comment: Please provide a screenshot or information about where you are setting these values? Are they the Power settings from the configure Power profile menu or are the in a Nvidia tool? If you provide more information we can help better. Things like version of Windows and things like that cna be useful as well.

Comment: Fixed. Windows 10, and win7.

Comment: Thanks for the edit guys. I hope there's a solution to my problem. It's such an annoying thing.